# Computing dot product between rows in dataframes in list and a vector in R

Tags: r

I want to get the inner dot product between each row of dataframes in a list and a vector; 
where there are dataframes in a list (so the dataframes should be kept separate in the list). I can do this when using subtraction but not for dot product. Please see example code below.

```
#Example data
V1 <- c(1, 2)
V2 <- c(3, 4)
V3 <- c(5, 6)
df1 <- tibble(V1, V2, V3)

V1 <- c(7, 8, 9)
V2 <- c(10, 11, 12)
V3 <- c(13, 14, 15)

df2 <- tibble(V1, V2, V3)

df_list <- list(df1, df2)
df_list

vector <- c(2, 2, 2)

df_list_subtract <- df_list %>%
  map(~ map2_df(.x, vector, `-`)) 
df_list_subtract

# Does not work
df_list_dotproduct <- df_list %>%
  map(~ map2_df(.x, vector, `%*%`)) 
df_list_dotproduct
# Does not work
df_list_dot_product <- df_list %>%
  map(~ map2_df(.x, rep(vector, each = x), `%*%`)) 
df_list_dot_product
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because the matrix are non-conformable, meaning you can only do mxn %*% nx(something) . So you just need to convert the data.frame to a matrix so it's 3x(something) and it should be ok:

You don't need the map2, unless you have another column to multiply with, but i don't see it here:

```
df_list %>% map(~as.matrix(.x) %*% vector)
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]   18
[2,]   24

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]   60
[2,]   66
[3,]   72
```

Answer (score 2):

`tidyverse` is not really very good in row-wise operation.

Here is a base R way :

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) apply(x, 1, `%*%`, vector))

#[[1]]
#[1] 18 24

#[[2]]
#[1] 60 66 72
```

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
df_list %>% map(~pmap_dbl(., ~c(...) %*% vector))
```

Comment: hmmm the output should be one value for each row; the dot product. Here there are still 3 variables. does that make sense? Thanks for the help

Comment: Updated the answer, I hope this is what you meant.